# Not able to load new form using jquery in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was looking at Ryan Bates screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised on how to load new form in the index.html.erb using jquery.

Here is my index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'New Mail', new_mail_path, id: "new_mail", remote: true %>
```

Here is my new.js.erb

```
$("#new_mail").hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>')
```

but this is not working. When trying to debug (in chrome), under Console, there are no errors but in Network, I am seeing "304 Not Modified" response instead of 302, any help ?

Thanks

EDIT - it worked, I eventually had to put "format.js" in create method *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$("#new_mail").hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>')
```

with

```
$("#new_mail").after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

Comment: Still not working, giving the same 304 Not Modified status code instead of 200 OK. So when I click on the link, nothing happens instead of new form being loaded